# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it why?

Tags: c#, sockets

Hi I am using TCPCLient and TCPlitner to transmit data but i am getting error not to connect 
below is my Code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    TcpClient tcpc = new TcpClient("192.168.21.46", 10);            
    NetworkStream nts = tcpc.GetStream();
    if (nts.CanWrite)
    {
         Byte[] sends = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text.ToCharArray());
         nts.Write(sends, 0, sends.Length);
         nts.Flush();
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TcpListener myListener = new TcpListener(10);
    myListener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        //Accept a new connection
        Socket mySocket = myListener.AcceptSocket();
        if (mySocket.Connected)
        {                   
            //make a byte array and receive data from the client 
            Byte[] receive = new Byte[64];
            int i = mySocket.Receive(receive, receive.Length, 0);
            char[] unwanted = { ' ', ' ', ' ' };
            string rece = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receive);
            label1.Text = rece.TrimEnd(unwanted);                  
        }
    }
}
```

this two buttons i have added in the same form and Ip apddress which is mentioned is my systems IP Address. Can anyone tell me why this Happen. Even I remove firewall setting also.

Comment: You press two buttons in the same time or I don't understand something...

Comment: is the port on the target machine free for you to use?

Comment: @Heather First button click to connect socket and then transmit and second button to recive data

Comment: ... I think you have no open socket to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have two different programs and one is listening while the other is sending. If you don't, separate them out. I'm thinking you have a networking issue but can't say precisely why it's blocked.

You're using port 10, which generally is too low for arbitrary application uses even if it's not currently occupied. If you're building a custom protocol, try to listen on a port above approximately 1000 (more a rule of thumb). You can look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959828.aspx or google for "tcp well known ports" for more details and to ensure you don't have a collision.

Try running your TCP listener, then open a command prompt and typing the following

```
telnet localhost 10
```

or use the port number you change 10 to. I tried your code and was able to connect to port 10 without issue. If you don't have the "telnet" program you can turn the feature on in your Windows. (search "feature" and choose "turn windows feature on or off" then turn "Telnet Client" on)

If the telnet program connects, you'll know that the issue isn't connectivity related. If the telnet program fails to connect then you'll know something is still blocking that port. Try a different port and re-test connectivity. Once telnet connects, you can then focus on the TCP client portion of your program.

Comment: Target machine is same even i turn on the feature of telnet but getting same problem and now i am using high port number but no luck.Actually the thing is i want to send some data from one exe to another exe and for that i am using this. But i get stuck to connect tcp.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your UI will hang on button 2 click because it's stuck on the while(true) loop so use BeginAcceptSocket(IAsyncResult r, Object state) for async.

Second you must use the loopback address or otherwise the firewall should block the port 10 assuming that it's not open. Also the TcpListener(int port) is obsolote and its better to use the TcpListener(IPAddress localddr, int port) and use both the loopback address.